# One more Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle

> For mandatory exercise does my prefix stand
>   Watch out for always in the grass I land
>   My suffix able of anything it desires
>   or to withstand pressure and times

What am I?

hint:

> In the orchestrated land I lie
>  Now it's time for some delicious pie

hint 2:

> Add a two-letter infix and for a bird you'll confuse me
>  We are the Lights who say: ...?

Comment: That title ... it feels like some users are turning into 'brands' :-/

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's a fact!

Comment: This is my first attempt at making a riddle for myself. Any feedback is welcome, especially critiques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> pecan

For mandatory exercise does my prefix stand

> PE (physical education)

Watch out for always in the grass I land

> Pecan nuts fall from the tree into the grass

My suffix able of anything it desires
or to withstand pressure and times

> can / canned food

Hint: *In the orchestrated land I lie*
*Now it's time for some delicious pie*

> Pecan pie is a thing

Hint: *Add a two-letter infix and for a bird you'll confuse me*
*We are the Lights who say: ...?*

> Lights who say "Li!" -> Pe(li)can

Comment: But I thought the Lights now say "Lekke lekke lekke lekke ltang loom loing"? :P

Comment: congrats on solving my riddle! All the explanations are correct. But you missed one in the first hint. Can you find that one out too?